# Validate Grid Data in ASP.NET MVC

Tags: asp.net-mvc, razor, gridview, webgrid

I have created an editable `WebGrid` in ASP.NET MVC 4 through which I will be able to edit, delete and update the data in the grid itself.

But I can't validate data in edit row in `WebGrid`.

I tried to search posts, without any result either, maybe I didn't use the right words.

How to do resolve this?

My code is shown below:

**View**

```
@model IEnumerable<Customer>
 
@{
    Layout = null;
    WebGrid webGrid = new WebGrid(source: Model, canPage: true, canSort: false);
}
 
<!DOCTYPE html>
 
<html>
<head>
    <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width"/>
    <title>Index</title>
    <style type="text/css">
        body {
            font-family: Arial;
            font-size: 10pt;
        }
 
        .Grid {
            border: 1px solid #ccc;
            border-collapse: collapse;
        }
 
        .Grid th {
            background-color: #F7F7F7;
            font-weight: bold;
        }
 
        .Grid th, .Grid td {
            padding: 5px;
            width: 150px;
            border: 1px solid #ccc;
        }
 
        .Grid, .Grid table td {
            border: 0px solid #ccc;
        }
 
        .Grid th a, .Grid th a:visited {
            color: #333;
        }
    </style>
</head>
<body>
    @webGrid.GetHtml(
        htmlAttributes: new { @id = "WebGrid", @class = "Grid" },
        columns: webGrid.Columns(
                 webGrid.Column(header: "Customer Id", format: @<span class="label">@item.CustomerId</span>, style: "CustomerId" ),
                 webGrid.Column(header: "Name", format: @<span><span class="label">@item.Name</span>
                            <input class="text" type="text" value="@item.Name" style="display:none"/></span>, style: "Name"),
                 webGrid.Column(header: "Country", format: @<span><span class="label">@item.Country</span>
                                <input class="text" type="text" value="@item.Country" style="display:none"/></span>, style: "Country"),
                 webGrid.Column(format:@<span class="link">
                        <a class="Edit" href="javascript:;">Edit</a>
                        <a class="Update" href="javascript:;" style="display:none">Update</a>
                        <a class="Cancel" href="javascript:;" style="display:none">Cancel</a>
                    </span> )))
 
    <script type="text/javascript" src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.8.3/jquery.min.js"></script>
    <script type="text/javascript" src="https://ajax.cdnjs.com/ajax/libs/json2/20110223/json2.js"></script>
    <script type="text/javascript">
        //Edit event handler.
        $("body").on("click", "#WebGrid TBODY .Edit", function () {
            var row = $(this).closest("tr");
            $("td", row).each(function () {
                if ($(this).find(".text").length > 0) {
                    $(this).find(".text").show();
                    $(this).find(".label").hide();
                }
            });
            row.find(".Update").show();
            row.find(".Cancel").show();
            $(this).hide();
        });
 
        //Update event handler.
        $("body").on("click", "#WebGrid TBODY .Update", function () {
            var row = $(this).closest("tr");
            $("td", row).each(function () {
                if ($(this).find(".text").length > 0) {
                    var span = $(this).find(".label");
                    var input = $(this).find(".text");
                    span.html(input.val());
                    span.show();
                    input.hide();
                }
            });
            row.find(".Edit").show();
            row.find(".Cancel").hide();
            $(this).hide();
 
            var customer = {};
            customer.CustomerId = row.find(".CustomerId").find(".label").html();
            customer.Name = row.find(".Name").find(".label").html();
            customer.Country = row.find(".Country").find(".label").html();
            $.ajax({
                type: "POST",
                url: "/Home/UpdateCustomer",
                data: '{customer:' + JSON.stringify(customer) + '}',
                contentType: "application/json; charset=utf-8",
                dataType: "json"
            });
        });
 
        //Cancel event handler.
        $("body").on("click", "#WebGrid TBODY .Cancel", function () {
            var row = $(this).closest("tr");
            $("td", row).each(function () {
                if ($(this).find(".text").length > 0) {
                    var span = $(this).find(".label");
                    var input = $(this).find(".text");
                    input.val(span.html());
                    span.show();
                    input.hide();
                }
            });
            row.find(".Edit").show();
            row.find(".Update").hide();
            $(this).hide();
        });
    </script>
</body>
</html>
```

Comment: Please show error message or the log

Comment: @B.S. Don't have error...